# percona-online-schema-change is taking a lot of time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, percona, percona-toolkit, aurora

We have a table with 600M+ records and using AWS Aurora with master-slave replication.

**Requirement:** 
We need to add two columns with index in `customer` table.

**Aurora Instance Specs:** 
Ram: 30.5 GB
CPU: 4 vCPU

I replicated the cluster and created instance with same configuration and ran the update process to newly created master instance to see how it works. But it's taking a lot time; ( already been 4 days ) and still running. Is there anything I can do to speedup the alter process?

**Command:**

```
pt-online-schema-change --execute --ask-pass --user=admin --statistics --chunk-time=1 --alter 'ADD COLUMN email_sha1 CHAR(40) DEFAULT null, ADD COLUMN email_sha256 CHAR(64) DEFAULT null, ADD INDEX email_sha1(email_sha1) USING BTREE, ADD INDEX email_sha256(email_sha256) USING BTREE'  D=example,t=customer,h=example.public.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking a hash of a phone number?  Why?  Indexing the phone number is arguably better than building a hash and indexing that.  For one thing, the phone number is always(?) shorter than the hash.

Kill the `ALTER` and rethink the task.

The likely reason for the problem is the randomness of the column being indexed -- Toward the end of the process, it will be slowing down to about 1 disk hit per row.  If you estimate 1ms per disk hit, I would estimate that it might take a week to finish.

What version are you running?  Can it add an index with `ALTER=INPLACE`?  That might let you (1) add the columns, then (2) in a separate `ALTER` do the `ADD INDEX` with `ALTER=INPLACE`, and not have to worry about it taking a week.

Still I question the need for the columns or the index.

If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Hi Rick, 

Sorry, that was email not the phone, already edited the question. Regarding the indexes and columns, we have a requirement that user can request for customer detail using email hash ( md5, sha1, sha256 ); md5 is already there, now we need to add sha1 and sha256. 

Its running on MySQL 5.6. Yes we can use `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` but how do we avoid locking as we will have traffic at the time of altering the table.

Please find the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` : [link](http://d.pr/n/TGJ1ja)


Thank You 
Bijay

Comment: MD5 is good enough.  If you have 9 _trillion_ records, there is only one chance in 9 trillion that an MD5 will be falsely dup.  If you are paranoid of a false dup, then check both the MD5 (indexed) and the email string itself.